# What does 4d tensor mean in Tensorflow?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, convolution

I need to perform convolution along the text line of fixed size. So essentially, a training example is of a form: `1*N_FEATURES` where `N_FEATURES` is equal to 3640 (140 characters encoded as one-hot, so 40*26=3640). I am trying to make sense of the example [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/skflow/issues/51), precisely:

```
def my_conv_model(X, y):
   X = tf.reshape(X, [-1, N_FEATURES, 1, 1])  # to form a 4d tensor of shape batch_size x n_features x 1 x 1
   features = skflow.ops.conv2d(X, N_FILTERS, [WINDOW_SIZE, 1], padding='VALID') # this will give you sliding window of WINDOW_SIZE x 1 convolution.
   pool = tf.squeeze(tf.reduce_max(features, 1), squeeze_dims=[1])
   return return skflow.models.logistic_regression(pool, y)
```

I do not understand why in this line:

```
 features = skflow.ops.conv2d(X, N_FILTERS, [WINDOW_SIZE, 1], padding='VALID')
```

we have : `[WINDOW_SIZE, 1]` and not `[1, WINDOW_SIZE]` ?
Since as far as I understand, convolution should be performed as following:

```
training example: '001010101000100101'
sliding window:   |---|
                   |---|
                    |---|
```

and so on, each window of size [1, WINDOW_SIZE] since its height is 1, and width is 3. But why does the example given says " `features = skflow.ops.conv2d(X, N_FILTERS, [WINDOW_SIZE, 1], padding='VALID'`)"?

Answer (score 2):

A 4-D tensor is exactly what it indicates: a tensor with four dimensions (subscripts, features, ...).

The notation for a sliding window in one dimension is a notational convention.  For convenience, we put the significant dimension first, and keep the **1** sizes for the end.  Thus, a 3-wide slice (1-D window) is given as a 3x1 window.

Comment: Do I get it right that a 3-wide 1-high in the 'expanded' form would be of shape [1, 1, 3, 1] ? Also, how do you determine what dimension is significant?

Comment: Yes, [1, 1, 3, 1] is the way I read the API.  "Significant" is not really a technical term: it's whatever holds the information that interests us.  Anything dimension with a limit of 1 is merely a place-holder.  Similarly, a colour image will have an "insignificant" dimension of 3 somewhere, the RGB components.